# How to call parameterized Index Action in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            List<tablename> lListsong = new List<tablename>();
            using (dbname dbcontext=new dbname ())
            {
                lListsong = (from z in dbcontext.tablenamewhere z.SongId ==id select z).ToList();
            }
            foreach (var Songchooesen in lListsong)
            {
                ViewBag.selectedsong = Songchooesen.SongName.ToString();
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

This is my Action has been defined in ABCControllers and want to access this action by using url www.urlname/ABC/12 but it is not accessible. I have used concept of routing in mvc3. Please help me

Comment: Can you post the route you configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following `route`,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ABC_details",
    "ABCController/{id}",
    new { controller = "ABCController", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, create an action Link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Related Data","Index",new { @id=12})
```

If this not work then create another action and use `RedirectToAction` to go into `Index` action